# HyperSQL keeps files locked after stop

Tags: java, hsqldb

I'm using a HyperSQL database in my software. When I start the Hsqlserver isntance it works prefectly. However after shutting it down it still keeps the .lck and .log file locked. When I kill my java process the files are unlocked. Any suggetsions on how to shut down the HSQLServer without killing my java process?

Code to start:

```
hsqlServer = new Server();
hsqlServer.setLogWriter(null);
hsqlServer.setSilent(true);
hsqlServer.setDaemon(true);

hsqlServer.setDatabaseName(0, "test");
hsqlServer.setDatabasePath(0, "file:" + path);

hsqlServer.start();

// Block till database is online
while (hsqlServer.getState() != 1) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Code to stop:

```
hsqlServer.stop();

// Block till its stopped
try {
    hsqlServer.getServerThread().join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Try to execute a SHUTDOWN statement before you stop the server

Comment: Thanks... Post it as a solution and i'll accept  it. Still find it weird that you have to stop it through a 'SHUTDOWN', before you can call 'stop()'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to execute a SHUTDOWN statement before you stop the server